# About $C_c^\infty((0,T)\times \Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega = \Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2 \cup \Gamma$ where $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ are open domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Gamma$ has measure zero. $\Gamma$ is the interface between $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$. Everything is bounded.

Let $Q=(0,T)\times\Omega$. If $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(Q)$, is it true that $\varphi$ vanishes on $\Gamma$?

It seems to me like it should, but apparently this is not true.

My reasoning is: obviously $\varphi$ must vanish on $\partial Q$, and $\partial Q$ contains $\{0,T\}\times \Gamma$. If you draw a picture it seems clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted two nearly identical questions: this one and [About the boundary of a set of the form $Q_i = \bigcup_{t \in (0,T)}\Omega_i(t) \times \{t\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/667729/); however the definitions of $Q$ in them are different. Please avoid such near-duplicates; and in any event provide references to related questions.

The function $\varphi$ is defined only on $C^\infty_c(Q)$; thus, one would normally discuss its vanishing on subsets of $Q$, which is a product space.  This space does not contain $\Gamma$ at all; $\Gamma$ is a subset of one of the factors in the product, not a subset of the product.

I think the meaning of the claim you are asking about is that $\varphi$ need not vanish on $(0,T)\times \Gamma$. I suspect that $t$ is the time variable. Thus, one would naturally say that a function does something on $\Gamma$, meaning it does it for some (or all) moments in time, i.e., sets $\{t\}\times \Gamma$.

Finally: please **provide references** to the claims you find unclear or dubious. Claims often appear such because the reader doesn't properly understand their context; withholding this context from Math.SE question  makes it less likely that the correct explanation will be given.

Comment: Thanks. I do apologise for posting such similar questions without linking them..