# About the boundary of a set of the form $Q_i = \bigcup_{t \in (0,T)}\Omega_i(t) \times \{t\}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, manifolds

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded (open) domain. For every $t \in [0,T]$, let $\Omega_1(t), \Omega_2(t)$ be open subsets of $\Omega$, with $S(t)$ the interface separating $\Omega_1(t)$ and $\Omega_2(t)$. $\Omega(t)$ is divided by these two subsets.

Define $$Q_i = \bigcup_{t \in (0,T)}\Omega_i(t) \times \{t\}$$ and $$S= \bigcup_{t \in (0,T)}S(t) \times \{t\}$$

Finally define $Q=Q_1 \cup Q_2$.

**QUESTION**: Let $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(Q)$. Why is it that $\varphi$ does not necessarily have to vanish on $S$??

$\varphi$ must be zero on $\partial Q$, does not $\partial Q$ include $S$? Please help me to see why not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, $\partial Q$ contains $S$ as a subset. This is easiest to see in the special case when   $\Omega_i(t)\equiv \Omega_i$ and $S(t) \equiv S$ for all $t$.

Therefore, a function $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(Q)$ must vanish on $S$.

I suspect that the author of the text you are reading actually meant to define $Q=\Omega\times (0,T)$. The latter looks like a more natural set to consider: it corresponds to $\Omega$ as $Q_i$ corresponds to $\Omega_i$.

Comment: Thanks user I believe you are right, I was too presumptive in my reading. I guess this is standard for Stefan problems. Do you happen to know of any good books where I can learn facts about these types of non-cylindrical domains and spaces of functions on them?